# How to generate a website accessibility report?

Tags: accessibility

What is the best way to check a website's WCAG 2.1 accessibility standard? I want to generate a report if a website's accessibility is of a AA WCAG 2.1 standard.

Comment: Answers to this question would be purely opinion-based, which is discouraged on Stack overflow. See [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Maybe you could rephrase your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Producing such report is called an *accessibility audit*.

For the *way* to check, the [Website Accessibility Conformance Evaluation Methodology (WCAG-EM) 1.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG-EM/) is the relevant standard, which is part of the WCAG 2.

It describes how to proceed in an audit:

[image]

1. Define the Evaluation Scope
2. Explore the Target Website
3. Select a Representative Sample
4. Audit the Selected Sample
5. Report the Evaluation Findings

Further, there is guidance on [**involving users**](https://www.w3.org/WAI/test-evaluate/involving-users/) and using evaluation tools, both of which are optional for conformance with the EM.

For most people, it’s impossible to evaluate all success criteria without using a tool.

There a plenty of **spreadsheet** solutions out there that help with the evaluation, some governments providing spreadsheets based on their national adoption of the WCAG.

The Web Accessibility Initiative created their own, simple [WCAG-EM Report Tool](https://www.w3.org/WAI/eval/report-tool/), and then there are several commercial solutions.

In my opinion, the following criteria matter:

### Combine automatic and manual testing

Only a smaller part of a site’s performance can be checked automatically, so you’d need a tool that guides you through the manual parts as well.

Ideally, the automatic parts would already be covered and taken into account.

### Avoid re-evaluation of common components

Modern sites, especially web applications, are constructed component-based, with components re-appearing on each page. These are based on the exact same code and will behave the same across pages. Like header, navigation and footer.

A page-based evaluation is therefore not very practical.

An ideal tool™ would take into account that these exist and re-use the component’s evaluation for each page that includes the component.

### Tools that provide these features

The market leader on accessibility tools is deque with their *axe* suite. They offer the [axe Auditor](https://www.deque.com/axe/auditor/), which starts evaluation of each page with an automatic audit, and then guides the auditor through the remaining manual checks, providing a combined report at the end.